# button element with border 1 px away from the real end

Tags: html, css

Quick and simple question,

is there a quick way to change on a button, the distance from the borders edge to the "real" edge of the element.

I dont want to get the border further away, i want that the background is spread 1 or 2 px more over the edge of the border.

Google does not show me the right solution or I'm searching with wrong terms, hope some of you can help me.

Since my question is not clear, here is an picture of what try to achieve

https://picload.org/view/rpogroor/test.png.html

Comment: Where is your code ? Also please post a pic or demo of what you want? Your question is not very clear please elaborate with proper example

Comment: do you mean `padding`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to use over here is the pseudo element. The trick is to have a normal button but not to use a border on that. Insted, use an `:after` pseudo element and using CSS positioning, we can simulate the effect you want, that is, the background spreads beyond the dashed border.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: #ede032;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 0;
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px;
}

button:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  right: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  bottom: 3px;
  border: 1px dashed #515151;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button>Hello There</button>
```

Here, the code is pretty self explanatory. I am having a simple `button`, where am setting some basic styles like `background`, `border-radius` and so on. Later, am having an `:after` pseudo where I use the dashed `border` which then I overlay over the `button` using CSS Positioning.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is un-clear. What do you mean by

> from an borders edge to the "real" edge of the element.

Are you trying to not display the border? If that's the case then you can always set the border to have a transparent color which would not show the border.

Answer (score 0):

You can add **[padding](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_padding.asp)** to the button to increase space between its contents and the edge of the button.

Is this what you want?

`padding:5px 10px ;`

This means that the : Top and bottom padding are `5px`.
Right and left padding are `10px`.

By default a button has `padding : 1px 6px;` So to increase it by 1 or 2 pixels, just use appropriate values.

```css
.spaced-out {
 padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<button>Hello</button>
<br><br>
<button class="spaced-out">Hello</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want [box-sizing:border-box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).

This will ensure that, no matter the border-width, the element will be the same size. I assume this is what you want although the question is not very clear what you're looking for.

Notice the difference between the boxes with borders:

```css
.flex-cont {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-item {
  margin: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
  flex: 1;
  border: solid 20px green;
}

span {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 45%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.one {
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.two {
  border: none;
}

.three {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-cont">
  <div class="flex-item one"><span>box-sizing: content-box</span></div>
  <div class="flex-item two"><span>No border</span></div>
  <div class="flex-item three"><span>box-sizing: border-box</span></div>
</div>
```

Here is a new JS fiddle based on your edit.

[New JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vhy5p8Lw/)

Comment: Why do you use :before instead of :after

Comment: So it gets inserted before the text in the DOM.